# Can "soft mind" be an insult?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

A man and his wife are having a fight. He is explaining something to his wife, and he's being mean to her because he's angry. At some point he says:

> Do you see where I’m going with this? Has your **soft mind** caught up with me yet?

Can "soft mind" be an insult in a context like this? And if so, how would you paraphrase it?

Comment: soft or mushy brain and mushy mind, I'd prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the expression has a derogatory connotation:

***[Soft-minded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/soft-minded)***

> Having a weak intellect or will.

(ODO)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that a soft mind refers more to being easily persuaded (and thus taken advantage of). For example, the first definition on wiktionary is

> Lacking courage and conviction; easily swayed, persuaded, or intimidated.
>   1963, Joe D. Batten, Tough-minded management, →ISBN, page 37:
>   The soft-minded manager often defers direct action in the hope that the situation will remedy itself.

When talking about someone not being able to figure something out, we usually say he has a **slow** mind, or we just say he is **slow**.